# iOS autolayout aspect ratio for UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch

I need to expand my subview in iPad as aspected ratio of iPhone.

How can I do this using `Autolayout`?

I had tried with view spacing constraint to all side and aspect ratio constraint to view .I had also decreased priority of spacing constraint but,I didn't get expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use size classes with auto layout, iphone portrait is compact-regular size, and on ipad, it can be regular,regular etc. so different constraints can install on different size class.